# Best Data Layer structure in APEX when trying to follow proper SOC?

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, dml

Backstory: I am currently working in a org that has not implemented proper SOC when it comes to our codebase. WE have some Trigger logic in the trigger files and most of our business logic intertwined with DML and SOQL operations (ie. no separation).  I have been working to separate the triggers into separate helper classes and would like to set up Data Layers to make our processes more testable but am not entirely sure how to implement this.

I am planning on using the Stub Api for testing and am planning on using this implementation: https://github.com/codefriar/SuperStub

My main question is in regard to how the data layer should be set up for DML and SOQL operations. I am planning to use the data layer classes for dml operations and soql operations.

***Should a data layer class be created for each object and then referenced throughout our apex code?***

EX. AccountDataLayer that could be called in various helper classes where ever account records need to be queried or modified?

PROS: Queries could be reused across multiple apex helpers

CONS: Each object that needed to be queried would need to its own data layer instantiated in the helper class.

OR

***Should a data layer class be created for each apex class?***

EX. AccountHelperDataLayer that would be used for all DML/SOQL in the AccountHelper apex class

PROS: Any query referenced in the apex helper would be in the related data layer class and could be more easily tested and deployed.

CONS: Some queries will be duplicated throughout the org which could pose larger difficulties if the underlying object structure where to change.

I'm sure the pros and cons lists could be extended further but those were just to get the conversation started. I have been trying to learn more about how to follow SOC on the force.com platform but could not seem to find a best practice for these implementations.

Comment: Kinda sounds to me like you may be trying to re-invent the FinancialForce [Apex Enterprise Patterns](https://github.com/apex-enterprise-patterns/fflib-apex-common) (no affiliation). The documentation links provided in that project should be good reading.

Comment: See [Composable](https://architect.salesforce.com/well-architected/adaptable/composable) chapter of newly published [Well-Architected](https://architect.salesforce.com/well-architected/overview) guide for high-level guidance.

Comment: Thank you for the resource @DerekF that git hub link does seem similar to what I will be trying to implement.

Comment: @identigral I did not know https://architect.salesforce.com/ even existed and I have been doing sf development for about a year and a half so I most likely have a lot of reading to do. Thanks!

Comment: Apex Enterprise Patterns - which I have used for years along with ApexMocks (stubbing framework) is well-described in Andrew Fawcett's book [Lightning Enterprise Architecture 3rd Edition](https://www.packtpub.com/product/salesforce-lightning-platform-enterprise-architecture-third-edition/9781789956719) and IMHO, a seminal work on how to design SOC

Comment: I've done this whole thing before and... it just adds tons of code and doesn't really make anything more reliable. It becomes much harder to debug and read the code as well. I wouldn't bother. (Datalayer, I mean, not Trigger improvements)

Comment: @CasparHarmer my push to try and use a Datalayer is so I can test my code with stubbed(fake) data. From my understanding if there are static queries in APEX code there is no way around testing with production data(SeeAllData=true) and/or inserting ever record you need for each test. With the later option we run into SOQL limits before any real testing can be done. 

Are you suggesting this is the better option?

Comment: No, you don't need to do that - you should use a test data generator class that inserts records prior to the unit test. Data created during a unit test is all removed following the test. I'm not saying completely avoid a Datalayer, but in my experience reducing complexity should be your ultimate goal.